# How to use this awk command without affecting the header

Tags: bash, unix, awk, dataset

Good nigt. I have this two files:

File 1 - with phenotype informations, the first column are the Ids, the orinal file has 400 rows:

```
ID  a b  c          d 
215 2 25 13.8354303 15.2841303
222 2 25.2 15.8507278 17.2994278
216 2 28.2 13.0482192 14.4969192
223 11 15.4 9.2714745 11.6494745
```

File 2 - with SNPs information, the original file has 400 lines and 42,000 characters per line.

```
ID  t u j l
215 2 0 2 1 
222 2 0 1 1 
216 2 0 2 1 
223 2 0 2 2 
217 2 0 2 1 
218 0 2 0 2
```

And I need to remove from file 2 individuals that do not appear in the file 1, for example:

```
ID  t u j l
215 2 0 2 1 
222 2 0 1 1 
216 2 0 2 1 
223 2 0 2 2
```

I used this code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next}$1 in a{print $0}' file2 file1 > file3
```

and I can get this output(file 3):

```
215 2 0 2 1 
222 2 0 1 1 
216 2 0 2 1 
223 2 0 2 2
```

but I lose the header, how do I not lose the header?

Comment: With sample data `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a' file1 file2 > file3` works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep the header of the second file, add a `condition{action}` like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next}
     FNR==1  {print $0; next}  # <= this will print the header of file2.
     $1 in a {print $0}' file1 file2
```

`NR` holds the total record number while `FNR` is the file record number, it counts the records of the file currently being processed. Also the `next` statements are important, so that to continue with the next record and don't try the rest of the actions.